# Kurento Media Server automatically creates an extra account "kurento" on installation

Tags: linux, webrtc, kurento

On installing kurento-media-server-6.0, it automatically created an extra account "kurento" and the password is still unknown. Although it does not have sudo access, but still an unwanted user account is a security concern.
On deleting user account, kurento-media-server does not function properly and has to be reinstalled. What is the significance of that account or why this account is being created?
[image: screen shot of details]

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how almost all "service" applications work on Ubuntu, and is actually a security feature. Installation of an application creates a user that is used only by that application and can have its privileges limited to only what that application needs.

For example, Apache uses `www-data`, Nginx uses `nginx` (or `www-data` if you install from certain sources), PostgreSQL uses `postgres`, MySQL uses `mysql`, Postfix mail server uses `postfix`, etc.

There's no reason for this to be a security concern. The password isn't "unknown" as you say, there is actually an **invalid password** -- meaning that it is impossible to log in to this account unless you give it SSH keys or use `sudo -u` (which only administrators can do anyway).

Just leave the account the way it is.